# Graficar 2 figuras 3D en Matlab al tiempo

Tags: matlab

¡Hola! Tengo un problema. He hecho 2 gráficas 3D en Matlab. La primera es un elipsoide:

```
syms x y z
[x,y]=meshgrid([-5:0.05:5],[-5:0.05:5]);
z1=(sqrt(-9*x.^2-y.^2+9))
z2=(-sqrt(-9*x.^2-y.^2+9))
plot3(x,y,z1,x,y,z2)
zlim([-4 1.5])
```

Y la segunda es un paraboloide de una hoja:

```
syms x y z
[x,y]=meshgrid([-5:0.05:5],[-5:0.05:5]);
z1=-sqrt(x.^2+y.^2-1)
z2=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2-1)
plot3(x,y,z1,x,y,z2)
zlim([1.5 4])
```

Como ven, cada uno está limitado por el eje x. Aun así, si las grafico al tiempo, usando el comando hold on, sólo se aplica el último límite.

```
syms x y z
[x,y]=meshgrid([-5:0.05:5],[-5:0.05:5]);
z1=(sqrt(-9*x.^2-y.^2+9))
z2=(-sqrt(-9*x.^2-y.^2+9))
plot3(x,y,z1,x,y,z2)
zlim([-4 1.5])
hold on
syms x y z
[x,y]=meshgrid([-5:0.05:5],[-5:0.05:5]);
z1=-sqrt(x.^2+y.^2-1)
z2=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2-1)
plot3(x,y,z1,x,y,z2)
zlim([1.5 4])
```

La pregunta puntual es: ¿Cómo puedo graficarlos al tiempo y que, además, cada uno mantenga esos límites en el eje z, de manera que se vean algo así como "unidos" o como si fueran una sola figura?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Limitado por el eje z*